# trying to set focus on some input after focusout on jquery

Tags: jquery

I know there are some posts regarding this but none seems to match my issue.

I want to set focus on a particular input after loosing focus on a button.

```
$('#more_button').focusout(function(){
  $('#input-text').focus();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sDnUr/

That do not behave like I'd like. Instead of going to "input-text" the focus goes on the browser address bar !

Comment: The code above works fine. What do you mean, it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're tabbing out of the last html element in your fiddle.  Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/sDnUr/7

```
<input type="text" id="input-text" /><br>
<input type="text" /><br>
<a href="#">foo</a><br>
<a href="#">bar</a><br>
<button id="more_button">more</button>
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">&nbsp;</a>
```

with your original javascript

Answer (score 1):

Do it with a small timeout and also use blur:

```
$('#more_button').blur(function(){
    setTimeout(function () { $('#input-text').focus(); }, 10);
});
```

I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sDnUr/2/).

Comment: I just tried in the fiddle but this doesn't seem to work ... It always goes back on the browser address bar

Comment: @Arno2501 I have updated the fiddle. I also use the blur event.

Comment: Are you sure ? After loosing the focus on the button my focus goes in the address bar of the browser on IE and Chrome

Comment: Actually mine does as well.  If I tab reverse it acts properly though... lets keep on :)

Comment: Do you want this to happen when you click() the button or when you blur() it?

Comment: for some reason if you tab out of the last 'tabable' element it goes to the address bar.  adding an additional element after the input makes it work: http://jsfiddle.net/sDnUr/6/